# Thrust::Sort very long compile time

Tags: cuda, thrust

I'm trying to compile a block of example code using Thrust in an attempt to help learn some CUDA.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and I've gotten other examples to compile. However, when I compile this example, it takes upwards of 10 minutes to compile. I've selectively commented out lines and figured out that its the Thrust::sort line that takes forever (with that one line commented out it takes about 5 seconds to compile).

I found a post somewhere that talked about how sort was slow to compile in Thrust and that was a decision that the Thrust development team made (its 3x faster at runtime, but takes longer to compile). But that post was in late 2008.

Any idea why this is taking so long?

Also, I'm compiling on a machine with the following specs, so its not a slow machine

i7-2600k @ 4.5 ghz 
 16 GB DDR3 @ 1833 mhz 
 Raid 0 of 6 GB/s 1TB drives

As requested, this is the build string that it looks like Visual Studio is invoking

C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v3.2\bin\nvcc.exe" -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v3.2\include"  -G0  --keep-dir "Debug\" -maxrregcount=32  --machine 64 --compile  -D_NEXUS_DEBUG -g    -Xcompiler "/EHsc /nologo /Od /Zi  /MTd " -o "Debug\kernel.obj" "C:\Users\Rob\Desktop\VS2010Test\VS2010Test\VS2010Test\kernel.cpp" -clean

Example

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
int main(void)
{
    // generate 16M random numbers on the host
    thrust::host_vector<int> h_vec(1 << 24);
    thrust::generate(h_vec.begin(), h_vec.end(), rand);
    // transfer data to the device
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_vec = h_vec;
    // sort data on the device
    thrust::sort(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end());
    // transfer data back to host
    thrust::copy(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end(), h_vec.begin());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There seems to be [a similar known issue](http://groups.google.com/group/thrust-users/browse_thread/thread/8bc57bf406d75569?pli=1) for Thrust sort_by_key, although personally I don't remember it taking that much time for sort. Perhaps it could help to notify them of these extremes? But if it's a compiler issue there might not be much they can do.

Comment: It does take a long time but 10 minutes seems a bit too much. Can you post the compile options you are using too ?

Comment: I'm not at the computer right now, but I was just using the default setting through Visual Studio. I just installed the Nvidia CUDA SDK and toolkit, installed the VC90 compiler (VS2008 express edition), copied the code from a Thrust example of Nvidia's website and tried to compile it. I'll post the exact compiler flags later

Comment: No answer?! Well I run into long compile times too after I started using thrust in my program. I'm on Ubuntu and use CUDA 4.0.

Comment: On CUDA 4.1, it takes a bit over a minute to compile a program with thrust::sort in it on my 2GHz, 4GB, Q6600, Windows 7 machine. You could move the Thrust headers into a precompiled header or tuck your entire sort function into a separate .cu file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler in CUDA 3.2 was not optimized for compiling long, complex programs like `sort` using debugging mode (i.e `nvcc -G0`).  You will find that CUDA 4.0 is much faster in this case.  Removing the `-G0` option should decrease compilation time by a significant fraction as well.